# Set value in column guided by result from select. SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a ready select.

```
SELECT 
    [c.MySiteRole].[Id],
    [c.MySiteRole].[EmployeeId],
    [c.MySiteRole].[RoleId],
    [c.MySiteRole].[SiteId],
    [e.Site].[Id],
    [e.Role].[Id],
    [e.Role].[Name],
    [e.Role].[RoleTypeId]
FROM  
    [MySiteRole] AS [c.MySiteRole]
INNER JOIN 
    [Site] AS [e.Site] ON [c.MySiteRole].[SiteId] = [e.Site].[Id]
INNER JOIN 
    [Role] AS [e.Role] ON [c.MySiteRole].[RoleId] = [e.Role].[Id]
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT TOP(1) [c1].[Id]
     FROM [Employee] AS [c1]
     WHERE [c1].[UserName] = 'MyUserName'
     ORDER  BY [c1].[Id]) AS [t0] ON [c.MySiteRole].[EmployeeId] = [t0].[Id]
ORDER BY 
    [t0].[Id], [e.Role].[Id]
```

In result of this select I have a list.

Next stage I need to compare the result [e.Role].[Id] from select with few other Id and they must be here, not in other table.

1. "first-guid-id"
2. "second-guid-id"
3. "third-guid-id".

If in result select will be coincidence with one of this id I need set for MyColumn update true. !important - coincidence  must be only with guid id from this list. For example if coincidence will be with one of them and in result `[e.Role].[Id]` will be other guid id - need set false for my update column. It's like "isOnlyProgrammerRoles"

Now I have my update script in this case

```
UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable]
SET [MyColumn] = CAST (CASE WHEN UserName like '%[^0-9]%' then 0  else 1 end AS BIT)
```

I need to update my script to something like this

```
UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable]

 SELECT [c.MySiteRole].[Id],
   [c.MySiteRole].[EmployeeId],
   [c.MySiteRole].[RoleId],
   [c.MySiteRole].[SiteId],
   [e.Site].[Id],
   [e.Role].[Id],
   [e.Role].[Name],
   [e.Role].[RoleTypeId]
 FROM  [MySiteRole] AS [c.MySiteRole]
   INNER JOIN [Site] AS [e.Site]
     ON [c.MySiteRole].[SiteId] = [e.Site].[Id]
   INNER JOIN [Role] AS [e.Role]
     ON [c.MySiteRole].[RoleId] = [e.Role].[Id]
   INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP(1) [c1].[Id]
               FROM   [Employee] AS [c1]
               WHERE  [c1].[UserName] = 'MyUserName'
               ORDER  BY [c1].[Id]) AS [t0]
     ON [c.MySiteRole].[EmployeeId] = [t0].[Id]
   ORDER  BY [t0].[Id],
      [e.Role].[Id]

  Compare the Result.Id with GUID id from list 'guidId', guidId', guidId'
  if one or more coincidence from list(only from list + no more guid id in the result){
    SET [MyColumn] = 1 like bit
   }
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results *might* help.  It is rather unclear what your question is.

Comment: Side note, I really recommend *not* having objects with `.` characters in their names, it makes things quite confusing. Aliasing an object with an even longer alias is also an odd design choice. Aliases for be more concise values, for example `MSR` for `MySiteRole` and `R` for `Role`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this solution doesn't follow the same table aliasing and it removes the unneeded brackets.  I'm not sure what you mean by "no guid in the result...".  Anyway, something like this

```
;with three_guid_count_cte(r_id) as (
    SELECT 
       r.Id
     FROM
        MySiteRole AS msr on 
       INNER JOIN Site AS s ON msr.SiteId = s.Id
       INNER JOIN Role AS r ON msr.RoleId = r.Id
       INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP(1) c1.Id
                   FROM   Employee AS c1
                   WHERE  c1.UserName = 'MyUserName'
                   ORDER  BY c1.Id) AS t0 ON msr.EmployeeId = t0.Id
       INNER JOIN (values (guid1), (guid2), (guid3)) t(v) on r.Id=t.v
    HAVING
       COUNT(*)>1;
UPDATE m
  SET [MyColumn] = CAST(1 AS BIT)
FROM
[dbo].[MyTable] m  
       INNER JOIN three_guid_count_cte tgc on m.????=tgc.r_id;
```